# complicated iteration through a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I am new to Python and programming. Have tried to search for answers but am really struggling with this one. Would really appreciate any help.

I have my data in a dictionary as follows:

```
averages_dict = {'probe1': [8.1, 7.9, 8.2], 'probe2': [7.8, 7.5, 7.7], 'probe3': [7.1, 6.6, 6.8], 'probe4': [6.7, 6.3, 6.5]}
```

where the items (values) in the lists, correspond to different individuals [A, B, C].

I am trying to write a script to get averages of probe1, probe2 and probe3 (keys in the averages_dict), for each individual (items in value list [A, B, C]). Ultimately I want a list of the averages for the probes, for each individual [ave(A), ave(B), ave(C)].

I hope that makes sense, but will hopefully make it clearer as I go.

So I am trying to write a for loop that first initiates an empty list (vals), appends the first item (value) of each probe list, calculates the average for that position (individual), and then appends this average to a new list (averages).

i.e. this is what I want after the first averages_dict iteration (for the first position in each list):

```
vals = [8.1, 7.8, 7.1, 6.7]
```

then calculate the average for this list and append average to new list (averages)
most of which I can easily do with this code:

```
vals = []
for item in averages_dict:
    vals.append(averages_dict[item][0])

ave_dict = dict()
i=0
for val in vals:
    i = i + val

ave = i / len(vals)
```

What I am struggling with, is how to then re-iterate through from the beginning of the dictionary again, in the second position of the lists, and so on, so as to get a final averages list for each individual, as follows:

```
averages = [7.425, 7.075, 7.3]
```

I realise I probably need some kind of counter and while or for loop before this code above, but cant figure out what?

Thanks in advance - any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's with the fonts?

Comment: Was that supposed to be code with comments? You need to select your text and hit the code-formatting button (the one with the braces) for code to display properly.

Comment: Yes it was. Thanks user2357112 and falsetru.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
averages = [sum(items)/len(items)
            for items in zip(*averages_dict.values())]
```

This is a list comprehension, and what it does is:

1. `zip` each set of values in the dictionary together, so that you get a list of values for each of the three individuals, rather than for each of the probes;
2. `for` loop through each of the individuals;
3. Divide the `sum` of readings for that individual by the number (`len`) of readings for the individual; and
4. Create a list of the averages.

I get:

```
[7.425000000000001, 7.074999999999999, 7.3]
```

Comment: You rock!! Didn't know about the zip function, and would have taken me AGES to figure this out on my own. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this with a for loop is:

```
avg = []
l = len(averages_dict)  #for loop easier to read/calculate len once rather than twice

for i in range(l):                       # in the example case, range is 0-2(len is 3)
    total = 0                            # initiate/re-initiate total
    for d in averages_dict:              # for each item in dict
        total += averages_dict[d][i]     # add dict[d] position i to total
    avg.append(total/l)                  # append total/len to avg
```

avg now equals:

```
 [7.425000000000001, 7.074999999999999, 7.3]
```